# Split string into list of words and separators

Tags: dart

Given this string:

```
one#two*three#four#five*
```

What is a fast solution to extract the list of Pairs?
Each pair contains the word with its separator character like this:

```
[
    ['one', '#'],
    ['two', '*'],
    ['three', '#'],
    ['four', '#'],
    ['five', '*']
]
```

Specifically in my case I want to use both *white space* and *new line* characters as separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a regular expression:

```
(\w+)([#|*])
```

See example Dart code here that should get you going: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ae3897b2221a94b5a4c9e6929bebcfce

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: dart is a relatively new language to me.

That said, regex might be your best bet. Assuming you are only working with lowercase a-z letters followed by a single character, this should do the trick.

```
  RegExp r = RegExp("([a-z]+)(.)");
  var matches = r.allMatches("one#two*three#four#five*");
  List<dynamic> l = [];
  matches.toList().asMap().forEach((i, m) => l.add([m.group(1), m.group(2)]));
  print(l);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on other responses here's my solution for *white spaces* and *new lines* as separators:

```
void main() {
  RegExp r = RegExp(r"(\S+)([\s]+|$)");
  var text = 'one two three \n\n four ';
  var matches = r.allMatches(text);
  List<dynamic> l = [];
  matches.toList().asMap().forEach((i, m) => l.add([m.group(1), m.group(2)]));
  print(l);
}
```

Output

> [[one,  ], [two,  ], [three,
>
> ], [four,  ]]

Explanation: https://regex101.com/r/cRpMVq/2